# How to run maven test from a Angular 2 webpage?

Tags: angular, maven, automated-tests

I have designed an automation framework using maven and now I want to make that test run from web dashboard.

I can run my test from command line using command:

`mvn clean test -DURL="http://www.google.com"`

But I want to give my team a flexibility to run the test from anywhere even though they are not using their laptop or machine. So if anyone click a `Start Test` on the dashboard the test will be executed.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You may use Jenkins tool to create a job of running your webpage test.

Then, if you want to invoke the test from the webpage, create a server side code which makes an http request using remote access API for jenkins:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API